# Spring - differences between @Named and @Component

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand the differences between these two annotations and how they affect injection in Spring. Consider the following piece of code -

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface ExternalPropertiesHolder {}
```

When I mark a class with this annotation -

```
@ExternalPropertiesHolder
public class SomeProperties {}
```

and then this dependency is injected using `@Inject`, it works perfectly -

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    private SomeProperties someProperties;

    @Inject
    public SomeService(SomeProperties someProperties) {
        this.someProperties = someProperties;
    }
}
```

However, when I replace `@Component` with `@Named` -

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Named           // --> Here!
public @interface ExternalPropertiesHolder {}
```

Then the injection fails with the usual bean not found exception -

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.hogehoge.SomeProperties] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I searched the Spring reference documentation, and all it has to say about the difference [is this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-standard-annotations-limitations) -

> JSR-330 does not provide a composable model, just a way to identify
>   named components.

What does that mean? Does it mean that I cannot use `@Named` to compose a custom marker like this? Or is there something else?

**P.S.**: Of course by `@Component` I am referring to `org.springframework.stereotype.Component` and by `@Named` I am referring to `javax.inject.Named`.

Comment: They should be the same. Just tried your case and It doesen't work only if you use @Named in a custom annotation. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

So I got the answer directly from Juergen Hoeller. [According to him](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14087?focusedCommentId=128221&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-128221), this line -

> JSR-330 does not provide a composable model, just a way to identify
>   named components.

means that the `javax.inject.Named` can only be declared directly on a given bean class. The composable annotation story just works with Spring's own annotations, which is exactly what I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, `javax.inject.Named` and `javax.anotations.ManagedBean` doesn't provide a composable model. Thus, can't be used with the same intent as `org.springframework.stereotype.Component`.

But i could see from the documentation, we could use `javax.inject.Qualifier` in this use-case, as it's meant to be used for defining custom annotations.

Did you gave `@Qualifier` from `javax` a try ?

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier           // --> from javax.inject
public @interface ExternalPropertiesHolder {}
```

Even the @Named is defined using @Qualifier.

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Named {

    /** The name. */
    String value() default "";
}
```